# How can I build a 3 x 3 tile based CSS grid with sidebar at full viewport height using grid-template-areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to without changing the DOM order, achieve this layout https://ibb.co/Y8TQLcC? I'm stuck with grid template areas.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas: 
  "one three";
   "two"
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.three {
grid-area: three;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.two {
grid-area: two;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `grid-template-areas` are defined incorrectly. Think of it as drawing a rough table / grid while telling css which cells of rows and columns act in which way on output.

Changing the `grid-template-areas` to following will work:

```
grid-template-areas: 
  "one one three"
  "one one three"
  "two two three";
}
```

The full code becomes this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas: 
  "one one three"
  "one one three"
  "two two three";
grid-template-rows: auto; height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.three {
grid-area: three;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.two {
grid-area: two;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="three">three</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's all? omg such a simple fix! thanks! but how to make it full height?

Comment: @AliciaY welcome, please upvote and tick mark the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: ok just add ```grid-template-rows: auto; height: 100vh;``` will do

Comment: @AliciaY done :)

Comment: @AliciaY i have also updated the grid-template-areas to look exactly like your required grid

Answer (score 0):

Your desired layout is a 3 x 3 tiles based grid layout at full viewport height.

In order to implement that, you have to fix the grid container element `.parent` [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) accordingly.

Additionally, set `height` of `.parent` to 100% of that of the viewport with the [viewport-percentage lengths unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#viewport-percentage_lengths) `vh`:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "one one three"
  "one one three"
  "two two three";
}
```